# Is it better to create a taxonomy term using the 'create' method of the base Entity class or the entity storage manager?

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I've seen multiple ways to programmatically create entities.

In this case I'm creating a taxonomy term. One is using this method

```
$term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
  'name' => $name, 
  'vid' => $vocabulary,
])->save();
```

Where I'm using the base entity class's public static create function. Another way to perform the action is using an entity storage manager. Like so:

```
$term = [
  'name'     => $name,
  'vid'      => $vocabulary,
];

$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create($term);
```

I looked up the 'create' function of the base Entity class and it seems to just be implementing what appears in the second example I provided. Is there a better practice between the two? Or does it not matter?

UPDATE: Also is there a difference between what the two return? Unless I'm doing things wrong I noticed that the top method returned an int which I'm assuming is the term id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a difference between the two shown snippets: The first will end up containing, in `$term`, either `SAVED_NEW` or `SAVED_UPDATED` because that is the value returned from [`Entity::save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Asave/8.5.x) (and from [`EntityStorageInterface::save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3Asave/8.5.x), indirectly used from the first).

So, also for the second snippet, writing it as follows would be an error.

```
$values = [ /* values to set for the taxonomy term */ ];
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create($values)->save();
```

The correct code to use in the first case would be the following one, especially if `$term` is later used (e.g. passed to a function).

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => $name, 
  'vid' => $vocabulary,
]);

$term->save();
```

(Don't forget to add the right `use` statement, which should always go on the top of the file containing the code.)

As for using one or the other snippet, you will often find Drupal code using `Node::create()`, `Term::create()`, or `Vocabulary::create()` in tests, which is (IMO) preferable than using the other snippet you are showing because at least it doesn't directly use the `\Drupal` class. (Just run `grep -rnwI ./ -e Term::create` from Bash in the directory containing Drupal core code, and you will see how many times it is used.)

Probably, after [[meta] Replace \Drupal with injected services where appropriate in core](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2729597) is marked as fixed, there will be no reason to avoid using methods like `Term::create()`, which has still the pro to be clearer and shorter.
In any case, if the service I want to use is already available in a class property, or I can inject the service I need in the class I am using, I would rather use that property or inject the service, instead of using a static/global property, directly or indirectly. (Dependency injection is preferable to global properties.)

Answer (score 3):

In procedural code it doesn't matter, because both do the same. The static `create()` is a shortcut for the second example. (The different result is because the first saves the term and the second does not, if you want the term as result then save in a separate step)

In OOP code a better way is dependency injection. The second example points in the right direction. Inject the entity type manager, store it in a class property and use it:

```
$term = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create($term);
```

How to inject a service depends on which class you want to use it in.

A lot of base classes include services already and if you are lucky such a common service like this is one of them. Sometimes, for example in a controller, there is a method to retrieve the service. Then add to the code above parentheses:

```
$term = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create($term);
```

See [ControllerBase::entityTypeManager()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/function/ControllerBase%3A%3AentityTypeManager/8.4.x).